# ciphersuites which does not need certifcates, RSA, SHA1 and use AES among opensll 1.0.2j, TLS1.2 supported ciphers list

Tags: tls

1. DSS based ciphers need certificate?
2. Which DH based ciphers do not need certificates among opensll 1.0.2j, TLS1.2 supported ciphers list?

Comment: `openssl ciphers -V ALL:eNULL| grep -vE 'Au=(RSA|ECDSA|DSS)'` gives you all ciphers which don't use a certificate for authentication.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, DSS suites needs certificates. In practice, many TLS libraries don't support these cipher suites anyway, so it probably doesn't matter.
2. You're basically going to be limited to the PSK (pre-shared key) suites.  There are several of these suites that support DHE and AES.  Support for these cipher suites while more widespread than support for DSS is still going to be more  limited than for the more popular suites, so you'll have to do some research to determine if this is a feasible option for your application.  I don't know off hand if these are available in OpenSSL 1.0.2j, but if not, you're probably out of luck.